# How do I locate elements inside a canvas for robotframework automation testing?

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework, tableau-api, ui-automation

I'm using robotframework and python to write automation test cases. But for Tableau graph, it is inside a canvas tag. I want to click some elements (dynamic) in the graph but I cant find the locator of the elements. I know coordinates works but it is just not practical in this case as the element position isn't fixed. Is there any way I can find the locator of the elements or any other way I can automate the click of the elements inside a tableau table or a canvas?

Comment: can you share the relevant html code? Without that and what you already tried providing an answer is quite hard.

Comment: for example in this website :https://public.tableau.com/app/profile/tableau.for.sales.analytics/viz/SalesForecastDashboard_2/QuarterlyForecastDashboard. I wanna get the locator of the bar chart which inside this tag <canvas class="tabCanvas tab-widget" style="display: block; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 734px; height: 202px;" width="1101" height="303"></canvas>.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, i see it's inside an iframe. When there is an iframe present and you want to interact with an element inside of it, you need to select that iframe.
So make sure you select the iframe using:
[Select Frame](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Select%20Frame)

To select a canvas in this case try to look to the upper levels. Here is a xpath for a random canvas on the tableau example u send:

> (//div[@id='view6637812712846354816_280773651190758291']//div//div)[2]//canvas

Comment: My problem is I want to locate the element in a canvas. For example on this website, I want the locator of a particular bar in the bar chart graph. How can I get their locator?